# Add db4o database to monodevelop in linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, db4o

I would like to include db4o jar files into monodevelop ide on Linux, I have researched a lot and I am not able to find anything that could help, could anyone help me with this issue or suggest me an ide where I could develop .net application with db4o database on linux

Comment: Actually you can use db4o on MonoDevelop. Please read this: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/db4o/